# Create new variable on Jenkins agent

Tags: jenkins, hudson, jenkins-agent

I using Jenkins 2.252 and Jenkins agent on Windows host.

I want to create a new environment variable on the agent, using existing variable `WORKSPACE`.

But all my attempts are in vain. I have tried:

```
${WORKSPACE}

${env.WORKSPACE}

${env:WORKSPACE}

%WORKSPACE%
```

I really don't understand where is my mistake :(

Comment: Workspace is job specific. Where in jenkins are you trying to set and how?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the dollar symbol? Following works for me...

```
node () {
    stage ('New environment variable')
    {
        println (env.WORKSPACE)
        env.NEWVAR = env.WORKSPACE
    }
    stage ('Still there?')
    {
        println (env.NEWVAR)
    }
}
```